# Using same Android binding class from 2 different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, binding, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to display data from the same class in two different layouts using Android's data binding.  The layouts are used to inflate the views in a `ListView`.  I already have it functioning for one, and I was hoping to use the same adapter class since it's easy enough to specify which layout resource to use.

The problem arises in the automatically generated databinding classes; since there are two layout files, it generates two of them, say, `LayoutOneBinding` and `LayoutTwoBinding`, and when I use

`DataBindingUtil.bind(inflatedView)`

I get one of the two, and they have no common superclass that I can assign the result to and still be able to use the contained data.  So, is there any way to reuse the data binding class across two different layouts?

Each layout file has a separate `<variable>`, but it is named the same and contains the same type of data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to reuse binding in case you have same variable names in both bindings. Every data binding extends `ViewDataBinding`. So, you have a super class which you can accept.

Here, you cannot directly set the variable like `dataBinding.variable1 = someValue`. But, there is an alternate way i.e. use of `#setVariable` function.

So in your adapter, your code would be something like as follow:

```java
dataBinding.setVariable(BR.variable1, someValue)
```

Ref: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html#implement-the-recyclerview-with-data-binding